# How to create interactive USSD menu?

Tags: java, protocols, ussd, telecommunication, ss7

I am currently using **map-api-2.1.0.jar** and **map-impl-2.1.0.jar** for handling USSD string from mobile phone. This is working fine and user is receiving USSD response.

**MapHandling Class**

```
public class MapHandling implements     MAPDialogListener,MAPServiceSmsListener,MAPServiceMobilityListener,MAPServiceCallHandlingListener,MAPSer    viceSupplementaryListener{
     @Override
     public void onProcessUnstructuredSSRequest(ProcessUnstructuredSSRequest procUnstrReqInd)
     {
      try
      {
        logger.debug("dialogId: " +procUnstrReqInd.getMAPDialog().getLocalDialogId() + " USSD String:"+procUnstrReqInd.getUSSDString()+"MSISDN:"+procUnstrReqInd.getMAPDialog().getReceivedDestReference().getAddress());
      } catch (Exception exp)
      {
      logger.error("USSD - error while loging ussd data ", exp);
      }
      ss7.request.UnstructuredSSRequest ussdRequest = new  ss7.request.UnstructuredSSRequest(procUnstrReqInd);
      Thread thr = new Thread(ussdRequest);
     thr.start();
 }
```

}

## ss7.request.UnstructuredSSRequest Class

```
   public class UnstructuredSSRequest extends SS7Operation implements Runnable {
       ProcessUnstructuredSSRequest procUnstrReqInd;
              public UnstructuredSSRequest(ProcessUnstructuredSSRequest procUnstrReqInd) {
          this.procUnstrReqInd = procUnstrReqInd;
       }
           @Override
          public void run() {
        logger.debug("[" + refId + "] Sending USSD response");
        sendUSSDResponse(validRequest);
       }
       private void sendUSSDResponse(boolean validRequest) {
        MAPDialogSupplementary dialog = procUnstrReqInd.getMAPDialog();
        USSDString ussdStrObj = MapProvider.getMAPParameterFactory().createUSSDString("Thank you for using CC service!");
        dialog.addProcessUnstructuredSSResponse(procUnstrReqInd.getInvokeId(),procUnstrReqInd.getDataCodingScheme(), ussdStrObj);
        dialog.close(false);
        dialog.release();
     }
    }
```

Above code is running fine and I receive "Thank you for using CC service!" response when I dial USSD from my phone. 

**I want to change this into an interactive USSD handler, I want to take input from user when he dials USSD code instead of sending him response and closing the session.** 

Kindly help me how can I maintain a session for user and take his input.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, I have similar requirement could you share the sample code with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using [Mobicents jSS7](https://code.google.com/p/jss7) project and above code is server side connected to HLR/MSC over SIGTRAN or E1.

If yes, you can see the sample code for server side at https://code.google.com/p/jss7/source/browse/map/load/src/main/java/org/mobicents/protocols/ss7/map/load/Server.java